# Audio longer than video when trimming MP4 files with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I just found out about FFMPEG and I need it to cut loads of MP4 files to the last 20 seconds of each. Each MP4 file has one video track and two audio tracks, and also have Variable Frame Rate.

I've been using this line of code:

```
for %F in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%F" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~nF_trimmed.mp4"
```

The trimming goes well but there's a problem with the audio. This error appears without canceling the trimming process, though I believe it has nothing to with my problem:

```
[mp4 @ 0000025740443740] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0000025740443740] track 2: codec frame size is not set
```

And when I drop the trimmed files to a video editing software, this can be seen:

[image: Editor Screenshot]

The second audio track is longer than the video track.

The **-shortest** command didn't do the trick. Maybe I'm just using it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I was messing around with `-shortest` and having issues with a longer audio track not being trimmed down to the length of the video. This is how I was trying to use it:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -shortest OUTPUT
```

After reading the documentation for the option a little more closely:

> Finish encoding when the shortest **input stream** ends.

With the above FFmpeg command there is *only* a single input stream. So the following command finally worked:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -i INPUT -c copy -shortest -map 0:v -map 1:a OUTPUT
```

where both the `INPUT`s are the same file.